# How can I set up a php script to run via cron?

Tags: cron, setup

How can I set up a php script to run via cron

I've created a file in the cron.d folder with the username as the file name:

```
/etc/cron.d/username
```

Inside of username file I placed the following cron command

```
0,30 * * * *   username /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

I'm actually trying to get the cron working for Open Atrium however upon checking Open Atrium status it shows no signs of the cron file being run.

Any help on this would be greate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **crontab** to add/remove/edit cronjobs.

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal.

First make sure the script is executable by running:

```
chmod +x YOURSCRIPT
```

Then run the following command to add your cronjob:

```
crontab -e
```

Add your cronjob like this:

`0,30 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php`

That's it!

Your can check the current user's `crontab` entries by running:

```
crontab -l
```

For more information about `crontab` run:

```
crontab --help
```

OR

```
man crontab
```

Comment: I still haven't gotten it to work. Question my /usr/local/bin/ folder is empty is this normal? I'm using php5-cgi

Comment: @Oudin try `/usr/bin/php-cgi`. You can search binary packages installed on your system by running `whereis -b <PackageName>`, In your case `whereis -b php-cgi`

Comment: Thanks just found it a few hours ago but goggling php-cgi location

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, PHP7: "whereis -b php7.0-cgi" result will be: "php7: /usr/bin/php7.0 .."

Answer (score 0):

Don't you also have to put the path to php?

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```